# Configure Android Studio to only replace with statement lambda?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lambda

I'm updating old Android code to finally take advantage of newer aspects of the Java language, and one of those is replacing tons of boilerplate anonymous classes with lambdas.

For example:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        tappedButton();
    }
});
```

It will auto-reduce this all the way down to an expression lambda:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id) -> tappedButton());
```

However, I really prefer the format of statment lambdas instead:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id) -> {
    tappedButton();
});
```

How can I configure Android Studio so that it will only auto-fix the code down to a statement lambda and not reduce down all the way to an expression lambda?

I know how to disable the Inspection so that Android Studio won't offer me the auto-fix to go from statement lambda to expression lambda, but I'm talking about when I run into an anonymous class that can be replaced with a lambda and I trigger the `Replace with lambda` auto-fix... I only want it to reduce to a statement lambda and not all the way down to an expression lambda.